# Overstayed while visiting in USA, trying to go home (Canada) & during covid

Tags: usa, air-travel, canada, overstaying

I was wondering if anyone would have info on this odd situation... I've overstayed my visit here in the US (from Canada) and its been almost 2 years coming up. I previously asked a question about leaving the us and issue with immigration but people said shouldn't be an issue leaving & that they cannot deny entry to my native country.

Now that there are more restrictions because I got caught up here since covid happened too & been dealing with grieve and stress alone (no family out here, boyfriend had passed). I am wondering if anyone know what I can do or has any info. I don't have the vaccine cause im not even documented here and

Just trying to leave and get back home to my family. Its been hard and long and a big struggle & covid made it harder (also being in such severe depression and isolation from my situation)

thank you if anyone has info! appreciate you so very much and bless you

Comment: Have you already read https://www.canada.ca/en/immigration-refugees-citizenship/services/coronavirus-covid19/travel-restrictions-exemptions.html?

Comment: You can get vaccinated in New York regardless of your (lack of) immigration status.  There are probably a lot of other places where this is true.

Comment: When you get back to Canada you will not have provincial health coverage for a few months (check and find out) so buy some private insurance. In Ontario (and I expect in other provinces) you do not need provincial health coverage to get a vaccine. You may need proof of address, such as your drivers license.

Answer (score 5):

Very, very easy.

1. drive to the Canada-US border
2. Show Canada border agents your passport, birth certificate etc.
3. Welcome Home, Eh.

You will not meet US immigration at any point, and even if you did it will not matter - the penalty for overstaying in the USA is deportation, and you are already on your way out.

There are some covid-related things, like a negative test within 72 hours and somewhere to stay for two weeks, but other than the advance test they are things you must comply with *after* crossing the border.

Comment: What if I'm planning to fly instead? I can't drive there because  i don't have a car and im really far.

Comment: Air travel exposes you to more scrutiny. If you drive, you are invisible until you appear at the Canadian border.